# Get PromiseValue of Async/Await syntax JS function

Tags: javascript

I learned JS a while back, before promises were a "thing". I'm trying to refactor some code with some new functionality. I can't figure out how to get the PromiseValue to evaluate it for an "if" statement. Here is the function:

```
async init() {
    if ("serial" in navigator) {
        try {
            const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
            await port.open({ baudrate: 9600 });
            this.reader = port.readable.getReader();
            this.writer = port.writable.getWriter();
            let signals = await port.getSignals();
            console.log(signals);
            return "123";
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(
                "There was an error opening the serial port:",
                err
            );
        }
    }
```

How can I access the `return "123"`? I'd like to put a conditional in there that I can evaluate, but when I try to console log stuff to trace my steps, I just get a "promise" in the console and then it says `"PromiseValue":123`. but I don't know how to grab that.

Comment: because you have not wrapped inside another async upon calling your init function, in other words you need a second async await

Comment: or `init().then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: gosh you guys rock. fixed my 4 hour problem in 5 minutes. if one of you wants to post an answer, i'll give you the points :D

Comment: Just an opinion but I feel it's a bad idea to jump into using `async/await` until basic promise use is understood. They are syntactic sugar for promises and it's not overly intuitive to the uninitiated that an async function always returns a promise

Comment: @charlietfl, i totally respect that input. i'm using some copy/pasted code from another forum and just trying to frankenstein it together for my purposes. I definitely appreciate the "then" syntax more and I can generally follow it easier.